# Windows Server 2016 Essentials vs Standard feature list?

Tags: windows-server-2016

Is there a straightforward comparison of Windows Server 2016 Essentials vs Standard Edition? Most pages that claim to compare actually only show the features of Standard vs DataCentre, including the main Microsoft page here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/windows-server-pricing

I understand the basic differences in licensing costs, but am more concerned with missing features such as Remote Desktop Services and Hyper-V.

I will be using it for a small office of less than 5 people and devices as a basic domain server as well as for SQL Server and occasionally virtual machines.